# Can I force Python to return only in String-format when I concatenate two series of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, string, concatenation, scientific-notation

I want to concatenate two columns in pandas containing mostly string values and some missing values. The result should be a new column which again contain string values and missings. Mostly it just worked fine with this:

```
df['newcolumn']=df['column1']+df['column2']
```

Most of the values in `column1` are numbers (interpreted as strings) like `82`. But some of the values in `column2` are a composition of letters and numbers starting with an `E` like `E52` or `E83`. When now `82` and `E83` are concatenated, the result I want is `82E83`. Unfortunately the results then is `8,2E+84`. I guess, Python implicitly interpeted this as a number with scientific notation.

I already tried different ways of concatenating and forcing string format, but the result is always the same:

```
df['newcolumn']=(df['column1']+df['column2']).asytpe(str)
```

or

```
df['newcolumn']=(df['column1'].str.cat(df['column2'])).asytpe(str)
```

It seems Python first create a float, creating this not wanted format and then change the type to string, keeping results like `8,2E+84`. Is there a solution for strictly keeping string format?

Edit: Thanks for your comments. As I tried to reproduce the problem myself with a very short dataframe, the problem also didn't occur. Finally I realized that it was only a problem with Excel automatically intepreting the cells as (wrong) numbers (in the CSV-Output). I didn't realize it before, because another dataframe coming from a CSV-File I used for merging with this dataframe on this concatenated strings was also already "destroyed" the same way by Excel. So the merging didn't work properly and I thought the concatenating in Python is the problem. I used to view the dataframe with Excel because it is really big. In the future I will be more carefully with this. My apologies for misplacing the problem!

Comment: Can you add the output of the `df.dtypes` to the post before and after the concatenation of the columns?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on my machine. So `df.dtypes` (as suggested by @KárolySzabó) would be helpfull and also a example dataframe, with which this behavior can be reproduced. It looks like pandas creates the string correctly, then converts it to a float and maybe the result back to string. That's quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

Type conversion is not required in this case. You can simply use

```py
df["newcolumn"] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{str(x[0])}{str(x[1])}", axis = 1)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce the behavior, @JoFriede observed?